# Convert objects to XML in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, xml, object, converters

In my work I am maintaining a legacy system (.net framework 4.7). It works a lot by transforming objects to xml (and saving to the database) and also the reverse, xml to objects.
Except that the current application, is working a lot with strings, to transform the object in xml.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(ms);

foreach (XmlNode item in xmlDoc.ChildNodes)
{
    if (item.Name == "xml")
    {
        foreach (XmlNode subitem in item.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (subitem.Name == "rs:data")
            {
                foreach (XmlNode sSubitem in subitem.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (sSubitem.Name == "rs:insert")
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode itemsub in sSubitem.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < itemsub.Attributes.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (itemsub.Attributes[i].Name == attrValue)
                                {
                                    dataGenerator = itemsub.Attributes[i].Value;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
 _rootElements.Add(
 new XElement("Books",
     new XElement("Book_year", _year),
     new XElement("Book_name", _book_name)
 ));
```

Example 3:

```
node.SelectSingleNode("DocumentType").InnerText
```

I'm thinking about rewriting the application (it should continue in .net framework 4.7), but I was wondering if there would be other ways to work with XML in a more modern way, unfortunately it has to be XML anyway, so I was wondering if there would be best practices for transform XML, or some package that helps in this service.

Thank you.

Comment: Your use case is unclear. Would [xml serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Extension to your class and use like as follow:

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static string ToXML(this YourClass value)
    {
        using(var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        { 
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(sw, value);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static YourClass FromXML(string xml)
    {
        using(var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(xml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass ));
            return serializer.Deserialize(sr) as YourClass ;
        }
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
var obj = new YourClass();

// fill properties

var xml = obj.ToXML();

// To reverse from string to obj, use:

var obj2 = XmlExtensions.FromXML(xml);
```